# Ggplot: plot - interaction - exclude --> prevent excluded points reset

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I would like to prevent reseting of the curve while choosing second variable to display with `selectizeInput`. For example in the code below we choose one value (`mtcars` dataset) in selectizeInput of **cyl (6)**, and exclude one point from the curve, then we choose second value of **cyl (4)** to display, and therefore the previous curve with **cyl=6**, resets itself (**the point which has been excluded, appears again**).

Is there any way to prevent this behaviour and while choosing second variable the excluded point stays "excluded"?

Example code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 6,
           plotOutput("plot1", height = 350,
                      click = "plot1_click"), 
           selectizeInput("valuecyl", "Select value of cyl:", choices=unique(mtcars$cyl), multiple = TRUE))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  # For storing which rows have been excluded

  vals <- reactiveValues()
  data_df <- reactive({
    data <- mtcars
    data <- data[data$cyl %in% input$valuecyl, ]
    vals$keeprows = rep(TRUE, nrow(data))
    data
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data<- data_df()
    keep    <- data[ vals$keeprows, , drop = FALSE]
    exclude <- data[!vals$keeprows, , drop = FALSE]
    print(keep)

    ggplot(keep, aes(wt,mpg,colour=as.factor(cyl))) + geom_point(data=keep) + geom_line(data=keep) +
      geom_point(data = exclude, shape = 21, fill = NA, color = "black", alpha = 0.25) 
  })

  # Toggle points that are clicked
  observeEvent(input$plot1_click, {
    data <-  data_df()
    res <- nearPoints(data, input$plot1_click, allRows = TRUE)

    vals$keeprows <- xor(vals$keeprows, res$selected_)
  })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are overwriting `vals$keeprows` and replacing it with `rep(TRUE, nrow(data))` every time the user selects a value in your `selectize`.

You need to update the `keeprows` variable by keeping the rows that were kept by the user and adding in the new rows coming from the extra selection.

To do that, I slightly modified your code:

```
  #added the data in the reactiveValues for convenience
  vals <- reactiveValues(keeprows=logical(0),data=mtcars[0,])

  #this observes the input and updates the data when the user adds a cyl value
  observeEvent(input$valuecyl,{
    #get the id (here rownames) of the points excluded by the user
    excluded_ids <- rownames(vals$data)[!vals$keeprows]

    #make the new data
    vals$data=mtcars[mtcars$cyl %in% input$valuecyl,] 

    #keep the rows that the user had not previously excluded.
    vals$keeprows = !(rownames(vals$data) %in% excluded_ids)
  })
```

Since I added the data in the `reactiveValues` and removed `data_df`, you need to replace `data_df()` by `vals$data` in your code for this to work.

Comment: I have only one small question to it, when i get reactive dataset (so in this case `mtcars()`), how i can keep the dataset to be reactive inside of the `observeEvent`?

Comment: not sure what you mean, if you have a reactive dataset coming from another part of your app, since `observeEvent` is a reactive environment you can use `vals$data=dataset()[dataset()$cyl %in% input$valuecyl,]`. You also need to update the initial value in the `reactiveValues`